# How to draw the stripboard planning for this diagram

Tags: pcb-design, stripboard

Can anyone help? I have no idea how to draw stripboard planning diagram for this diagram. I have to solder but I cant even start without stripboard planning diagram. Thanks in advance.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/W93Hb.jpg)

Comment: Tried pen and paper?

Comment: Asking for advice on becoming an artist for electronics may be off-topic here. However, I do recommend the following that can help you out: Practice drawing by looking at an object and seeing how it relates to the circuit. There's also some schematic editors that will allow you to export your schematic to a see 3D representation of your circuit. Take some night classes in art school to strengthen your perspective of morphology and you'll be able to draw anything. Lastly, print out pictures of the components, and put it underneath your drawing canvas so you can draw an outline.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you had a piece of stripboard in front of you, together with all the components for this circuit. You would:

- Choose one component from the circuit diagram and place it on the stripboard so that the component is on the plain side of the board and its pins emerge on the copper side, each pin on a different strip.
- Choose another component from the circuit diagram which needs to connect to the first component.
- Place the new component on the stripboard so that any pin that needs to connect to a pin of the the first component is on the same strip as that pin, and any pin that doesn't connect is on a strip that you haven't used yet.
- Repeat until you have placed all the components.

In order to do this for any but the simplest of circuits you'll probably have to:

- Use some jumper wires to link different strips on the board together, and/or
- Use a track breaking tool (or suitable size drill) to break the copper tracks at certain places so as to separate different parts of the same strip.

So to plan your layout, take some lined or squared paper which will represent your stripboard, and draw on it where the components and any jumper wires will go. Mark with an X any places where you need to break the track. You'll probably find you will want to revise the design several times and each revision will become neater and more compact, and probably need fewer jumpers or track breaks.

Finally, check your design very carefully - the best way is to draw out the circuit diagram from your stripboard design and check that it matches the original diagram you worked from. Pay special attention to components like transistors and ICs as the pinouts are not always shown as clearly as in your diagram, and for some parts there may even be different versions with different pinouts in the same package!

There are software packages that can do stripboard layout, such as the nice but sadly buggy and unmaintained [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/), but for a circuit like the one you've shown, paper and pencil is perfectly good.

Finally, I see that you're asking about a mains-powered circuit. I strongly advise that as a beginner in electronics you don't try and build anything using mains voltages without some supervision from someone more experienced who can check your work for safety. The way round this would be to buy an AC/AC power supply unit where the transformer is already safely enclosed. Even low-voltage circuits can be a fire hazard though, if enough current is available from the power supply or battery.